# Модификаторы функций и их отсутвие в языковом стандарте

Tags: синтаксис, c++, функции

Почему в реализации компилятора есть функции с обратным вызовом с модификаторами (например APIENTRY, PASCAL и т.д.) а в языковом стандарте про модификаторы ничего не сказано?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не модификаторы и не ключевые слова, это макросы (обратите внимание на то, что они написаны капсом, как это принято для названий макросов). Если вы использвете Visual Studio, то узнать, в какой именно текст раскрываются эти макросы, вы можете, поставив на них курсор и нажав F12. Вообще у MS полным-полно таких макроссов, которые, разумеется, являются их собственным "изобретением", и не встречаются в других реализациях языка, а потому и в стандарте о них нет ни слова

UPD

Вышеперечисленные макросы в VS определяются следующим образом:

```
#define APIPRIVATE  __stdcall
#define PASCAL      __stdcall
```

**Обновление**

> ведь по языковому стандарту между именем и типом возвращаемого значения ничего не может быть

я не эксперт в C++ и всех тонкостей стандарта не знаю, однако сильно сомневаюсь, что вы правы.

Скажем вот такой объявление функции является вполне корректным, несмотря на то, что между int и и менем функции стоит модификатор const:

```
int const someFunc()
```

А на [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zxk0tw93.aspx) синтаксис **__stdcall** прямо говорит о том, что этот модификатор ставится между типом возвращаемого значения и именем функции

Более того, вот такой пример

Comment: Но ведь даже если после преобразования макроса, например, WINAPI в __stdcall функция становится, например,    int __stdcall WinMain ();, а я не понимаю, почему оно правильно компилируется, ведь по языковому стандарту между именем и типом возвращаемого значения ничего не может быть.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: просто стандарт это одно, а реальная жизнь немножко другое. Вот и приходиться разработчикам языка чуточку дошлифовывать, что бы оно все работало.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что архитектура x86 — [странная](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/14/229387.aspx). Именно она (то есть, компания Intel), а не прихоть разработчиков MSVC, определяет многообразие calling conventions.

Исторический экскурс: [[1]](http://bit.ly/1xQfGZw), [[2]](http://bit.ly/1Fg71jK), [[3]](http://bit.ly/1ABya11), [[4]](http://bit.ly/1urLTPp), [[5]](http://bit.ly/157LywN).